# Implicit type argument in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

given that I have ViewModels with strongly typed parameter
and I use NavigationService that accept type of page as a parameter,
when parameter of incorrect type is passed to the Navigate method.
then I want the compiler to throw an error.

I've written following so far:

```
interface IPageViewModel<TParameter>    

void Navigate<TViewModel, TParameter>(TParameter argument) 
            where TViewModel : IPageViewModel<TParameter>;

class PageWithStringParameter : IPageViewModel<string>
```

Why this does not work?

```
navigationService.Navigate<PageWithStringParameter>("some string");
```

If I pass PageWithStringParameter as a TViewModel argument, TParameter must be of type string, since it implemets IPageViewModel.
Passing TParameter type argument is redundant.

Is there any way, how to avoid writing this:

```
navigationService.Navigate<PageWithStringParameter, string>("some string");
```

The compiler errors are quite confusing, especialy if I have also parameterless overload of NavigateMethod

Comment: Why are you creating the generic method with two parameters when you only actually need one?

Comment: because I want this to thow a compiler error:
navigationService.Navigate<PageWithStringParameter>(123);

but I want this:
navigationService.Navigate<PageWithStringParameter>("some string");

to navigate to an instace of PageWithStringParameter and pass "some string" argument

Comment: @Liero `Navigate<PageWithStringParameter, int>(123)` gives you compile time error

Comment: @Sergey: I know :) It just seemed redundant to me, to specify also type of parameter, because it could be interited from PageWithStringParameter. As you mentioned, all type arguments, or none of them can be specified. There is probably no way how to simplify my Navigate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `Navigate` has two generic two type arguments. You are providing only one. Type arguments cannot be specified partially. You either specify all of them, or none of them (all should be resolved implicitly in that case)

Answer (score 3):

An interface approach you could consider is to have Navigate without parameters return an operations object like below:

```
public class Operations<TViewModel>
{
    void To<TParameter>(TParameter argument);
}

Operations<TViewModel> Navigate<TViewModel>();
```

So you can invoke the operation as such:

```
navigationService.Navigate<PageWithStringParameter>().To("some string");
```

Unfortunately you loose the ability to restrict type with the "where" clause, but you can do it with code.

Comment: this code does not restrict the parameter type at all. Aren't you missing where?